# Saving modified collection of records into instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of objects that are being pulled from a third party service. I am using an each_with_index block to iterate over them and make changes to one of the attributes in each object (Payment_Due_Date__c). I'd like to have these records saved into a new instance variable that I can pass to my view and iterate over inside a table.

```
@payments.each_with_index do |x, i|
    loan_start_plus = @loan_start_date + i.months
    x.Payment_Due_Date__c = 3.business_days.before(loan_start_plus)
end
```

How can I save the updated records into a collection that I can then pass into my view?

Comment: They're already in a collection you can pass to your view, `@payments`.

Comment: @DaveNewton When I pass payments to my controller, they don't include the modification I am making inside the each_with_index block. I'm modifying the date in one of the fields and when I pass payments to my view, no date is present.

Comment: Then something else is wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton You're right. I just tried Andrey's answer which I figured would be correct. For some reason the code inside my each block isn't saving the value for it to be passed into the view.

Comment: What do you mean by "not saving"? Did you mean you wanted the changes to appear in a *different* view, e.g., after reloading the payments?

Comment: When I iterate through payments in my view, the Payment_Due_Date__c is empty. However, when I iterate through payments with the block in my controller that I posted above and puts the results as it's iterating, it shows a Payment_Due_Date__c.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
@payments.each_with_index.map do |x, i|
    loan_start_plus = @loan_start_date + i.months
    x.Payment_Due_Date__c = 3.business_days.before(loan_start_plus)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I think this solution would typically work if it were a standard ruby array or hash but because this is a collection it's not solving my problem.

Comment: I did test it with a collection and it worked. I'm using rails 4 and ruby 2.2.1

Comment: It must be because the formatting of this collection isn't a standard ruby data list. It's from a Salesfroce REST api call.